# Grouping MySQL data

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this table, lets call it table one.

```
+----+---------+-----------------+
| id | link_id | url             |
+----+---------+-----------------+
|  1 |       1 | www.example.com |
|  2 |       1 | www.abc.com     |
|  3 |       1 | www.test.com    |
|  4 |       1 | www.t1.com      |
|  5 |       1 | www.newtest.com |
|  6 |       1 | www.testing.com |
|  7 |       1 | www.abc.com     |
|  8 |       1 | www.example.com |
|  9 |       1 | www.web1.com    |
| 10 |       1 | www.web2.com    |
| 11 |       2 | www.dear.com    |
| 12 |       2 | www.google.com  |
| 13 |       2 | www.flowers.com |
| 14 |       2 | www.yahoo.com   |
| 15 |       2 | www.abc.com     |
| 16 |       2 | www.dell.com    |
| 17 |       2 | www.web.com     |
| 18 |       2 | www.example.com |
| 19 |       2 | www.test.com    |
| 20 |       2 | www.abc.com     |
+----+---------+-----------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The link_id is sort the primary identifier in the table. It tells me which urls appear in link 1, link 2 , etc.

What I want to acomplish is: 
 1. Get all the unique URLs, 
 2. Show which links the URL belongs to

So an example output would be:

```
+-----------------+---------+
| url             | link_id |
+-----------------+---------+
| www.example.com |       1 |
| www.example.com |       2 |
| www.abc.com     |       1 |
| www.abc.com     |       2 |
| www.test.com    |       1 |
| www.test.com    |       2 |
| www.t1.com      |       1 |
| www.newtest.com |       1 |
| www.testing.com |       1 |
| www.web1.com    |       1 |
```

...and so on.

So you can see that www.example.com appears twice since it is associated with both links 1 and 2, but web1.com appears only once since it belongs only to link 1.

I have tried several different `group by` but I only end up scratching my head even more.

Any help is appreciated. Here is the table dump if anyone needs:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link_id` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `link_id`, `url`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'www.example.com'),
(2, 1, 'www.abc.com'),
(3, 1, 'www.test.com'),
(4, 1, 'www.t1.com'),
(5, 1, 'www.newtest.com'),
(6, 1, 'www.testing.com'),
(7, 1, 'www.abc.com'),
(8, 1, 'www.example.com'),
(9, 1, 'www.web1.com'),
(10, 1, 'www.web2.com'),
(11, 2, 'www.dear.com'),
(12, 2, 'www.google.com'),
(13, 2, 'www.flowers.com'),
(14, 2, 'www.yahoo.com'),
(15, 2, 'www.abc.com'),
(16, 2, 'www.dell.com'),
(17, 2, 'www.web.com'),
(18, 2, 'www.example.com'),
(19, 2, 'www.test.com'),
(20, 2, 'www.abc.com');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT url, GROUP_CONCAT(link_id) 
  FROM table1 
 GROUP 
    BY url;
```

That'll give you all the distinct URLs, each with a list of link ids

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't a DISTINCT list work?  Does order matter?

```
SELECT DISTINCT url, link_id
FROM `table1`
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, it sounds like all you need is a DISTINCT clause:

```
select distinct url, link_id from table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select url, link_id
From Table1
Group By url, link_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table group by link_id,url
```

Answer (score 1):

Well imho you should group by both link_id and url, and than maybe sort by url so the same urls are together.

```
  SELECT url, link_id FROM table1
  ORDER BY url
  GROUP BY url, link_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url, link_id FROM table1;
```